# How to stretch menu by wrapper height?

Tags: html, css

How to stretch menu by wrapper height?

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 40px;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 20%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.right {
    background-color: #aaa;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ha5jB/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're looking for *faux columns*, in case you want to give it another go yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/ha5jB/3/)

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 20%;
      height: 100%;
}
.right {
    background-color: #aaa;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what that means.